# German sentence corpus with cloze norms

Tags: corpora, resource-request, german

I wish to conduct research on German based on cloze probabilities. Cloze probabilities are not trivial to collect, so I am asking if there exist any publicly available corpora of German sentences with cloze ratings.

Comment: Please justify the downvote. It seems corpus inquiries are not off topic.

Comment: Someone could downvote it because it shows no research effort.

Comment: I guess I could throw a "I have googled every meaningful phrase and come up with nothing" up there, but that'd just be noise IMO.

Comment: I have also privately obtained a few corpora by mailing researchers, but it would be great to know about a *public* corpus.

Answer (score 1):

You can always try the Potsdam Sentence Corpus which is a collection of sentences (n=144) with every word cloze rated with a number of other predictors as well such as frequency etc.

Comment: just realized this is two years too late... sorry

Comment: Late answers aren't a problem on Stack Exchange, so there's nothing to be sorry about!

Comment: The PSC is indeed an example of what I was looking for and I have worked with it for quite some time, but it is not *publicly* available is it? You can write Reinhold Kliegl and he will gladly make it available, but if there is an open link/website, that would be great.